# How to create circle/square shapes using React with text inside them without using SVG images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What is the way to create circle and square shapes using React which can contain custom text inside them without using SVG images?
An example: [image]

I have tried the following code but it doesn't render any shapes:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Circle(){
  return(
    <div height="110" width="500">
      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="55"
        r="45"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#F0CE01"
        strokeWidth="4"
      />
    </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: Rectangles/squares and circles/ovals can be created with just css if you want to put text in them. For rect, just change `width` and `height` properties, for ellipse, just change `width`, `height`, and `border-radius` properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use even a `div` tag to do that. Just add `border-radius` to create a circle.

React example: https://codesandbox.io/s/shapes-qbf1f

Here is a snippet for a quick overview:

```css
.square {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <p class="text">Square text</p>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <p class="text">Circle text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I put the styles inline, the circle doesn't render `<div style={{ circle: {
display: "flex",
width: "100px",
height: "100px",
backgroundColor: "green",
borderRadius: "50%",}, 
}}
>
<text> cLICK Me </text>
</div>`

Comment: Add `style: {{ margin: "auto"` to `text` and it will be work too

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there is no `circle` property in the style. If you want add inline style then you need this:
`<div style={{ display: "flex",  width: "100px", height: "100px", backgroundColor: "green", borderRadius: "50%"  }}><text style={{ margin: "auto" }}>{text}</text></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it with simple React

```
let initials = ("AA");
let color = ("#606060");
const customStyle =
{
 display: "flex",
 height: "30px",
 width: "30px",
 borderRadius: "100px",
 color: "white",
 background: color,
 margin: "auto",
 marginRight: 5,
 marginTop: -4
}

return(
    <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
     <div style={customStyle}>
     <span style={{margin: 'auto'}}>{initials}</span>
    </div>
        Profile
    </div>
)
```